# Eclipse doesn't break on ANY handled/unhandled exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I wanted to see how Eclipse breaks on handled/unhandled exceptions. I added the following lines of code as the first lines in my startup activity to deliberately cause an exception. Eclipse never breaks into the code on the exception:

```
try
{
  String s = "abc";
  int v = Integer.valueOf(s);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  try
  {
    String s = "abc";
    int v = Integer.valueOf(s);
  }
  catch(Exception ex2)
  {
    String s = "";
  }
}
```

In Eclipse, to enable the breakpoint handling, I enabled the following under Run > Add Java Exception Breakpoint...

Exception

Suspend on caught exceptions

Suspend on uncaught exceptions

Comment: What exactly do you want Eclipse to do? Do you want it to crash completely?

Comment: No, I expect it to do exactly what it says: break when the exception is encountered. It should have breaked on the line int v = Integer.valueOf(s);

Comment: How are you launching this..what is it?